# How to calculate sum of prime numbers from list of integers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struck and need help with this..
I want to find the sum of prime numbers from a given list of integers. Here are a few test cases for the same.

```
n([3,3,1,13])

19

n([2,4,6,9,11])

13

n([-3,0,1,6])

0
```

The Code that I have written is as follows but it fails with the test cases above..

```
def sumprimes(n):
    sum1 = 0
    for i in range(0,len(n)):
        num = n[i]
        if num > 1:
            for j in range(2, int(num**0.5)+1):
                if num%j != 0:
                    sum1 = sum1 + num
        else:
            sum1 = 0
    return(sum1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
        for j in range(2, int(num**0.5)+1):
            if num%j != 0:
                sum1 = sum1 + num
```

you are summing `num` for each number in the range that didn't divide.
you should sum just if **all** of them didn't divide.

Simple way to do this is:

```
        prime = True
        for j in range(2, int(num**0.5)+1):
            if num%j == 0:
                prime = False
                break
        if prime:
            sum1 = sum1 + num
```

Or in a more *pythonic* way using `all()`:

```
        if all(num%j != 0 for j in range(2, int(num**0.5)+1)):
            sum1 = sum1 + num
```

Comment: That works for me, but you can improve it by searching for multiple questions about how to find a prime number in python, on this site.

Comment: @KennyOstrom sure, but that's not what the OP question about ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do everything in one function.  I separated out the rest of the logic, but I'll leave isprime to you:

```
def isprime(x):
    # Replace this with your code
    # separate function so it can have its own tests
    return x in [3, 13, 11, 2]

def sum_prime_numbers_in_list(l):
    return sum([x for x in l if isprime(x)])

if 19 != sum_prime_numbers_in_list([3, 3, 1, 13]):
    raise ValueError
else:
    print 'pass'

if 13 != sum_prime_numbers_in_list([2, 4, 6, 9, 11]):
    raise ValueError
else:
    print 'pass'

if 0 != sum_prime_numbers_in_list([-3, 0, 1, 6]):
    raise ValueError
else:
    print 'pass'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lower = int(input("Enter lower range: "))
upper = int(input("Enter upper range: "))
lst=[]
print("Prime numbers between",lower,"and",upper,"are:")

for num in range(lower,upper + 1):

   if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,num):
           if (num % i) == 0:

               break
       else:
           print(num)
           lst.append(num)
print(lst)
sum=0
for i in lst:
    sum=sum+i
print('sum of all prime numbers=%d'%sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum_primes(a):
    sum = 0
    for num in a:  
       if num > 1:  
           for i in range(2,num):  
               if (num % i) == 0:  
                   break  
           else:  
               sum = sum + num
    if sum < 1:
        print("sum_primes(" + str(a) + ") --> " + "None")
    else:
        print("sum_primes(" + str(a) + ") --> " + str(sum))
sum_primes([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
sum_primes([2, 3, 4, 11, 20, 50, 71])
sum_primes([])

#code by Rushabh Koradia
```

Comment: `sum` is a built-in in python so you should avoid using it as a variable name

Answer (score 0):

The Answer should be this. [You should try this code, in this link.[Gist](https://gist.github.com/Jayhalani/aa7ddf085bea9d1057644a93753f8813)]

```
def sumprimes(n):
sum1 = 0
for i in range(0,len(n)):
    num = n[i]
    if num > 1:
        prime = True
        for j in range(2, int(num**0.5)+1):
            if num%j == 0:
                prime = False
                break
        if prime:
            sum1 = sum1 + num
        #else:
        #    sum1 = 0
return(sum1)
```

Comment: This code fails the test case sumprimes([3,3,1,13])

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Jayhalani/aa7ddf085bea9d1057644a93753f8813 Get the full code from this link.

Answer (score 0):

```
> def sumprimes(n):
    sum=0
    fact=[]
    for i in range (0,len(n)):
        num=n[i]
        if num>1:
            fact=[]
            for j in range (1,num+1):
                if num%j==0:
                    fact=fact+[j]
        if fact==[1,num]:
            sum=sum+num


    return(sum)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumprimes(n):
    s=0
    f=[]
    for i in range (0,len(n)):
        num=n[i]
        if num>1:
            f=[]
            for j in range (1,num+1):
                if num%j==0:
                    f=f+[j]
                if f==[1,num]:
                    s=s+num
    return(s)
```

Comment: Perhaps add a few comments or an overview to help those learning understand the approach better.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumprimes(l):
    def findprime(n):
        if n > 1:
            # check for factors
            for i in range(2, n):
                if (n % i) == 0:
                    return False
                    break
            else:
                return True
        # if input number is less than
        # or equal to 1, it is not prime
        else:
            return False
    sum = 0
    for x in l:
        if findprime(x):
            sum += x
    print(sum)
```

Comment: def findprime(n):
        if n > 1:
            # check for factors
            for i in range(2, n):
                if (n % i) == 0:
                    return False
                    break
            else:
                return True
        # if input number is less than
        # or equal to 1, it is not prime
        else:
            return False

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey Manish, no need to comment on your own posts. You can it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73240331/edit).

Answer (score -1):

```
s=input("Enter :")
arr=s.split(",")
sum=0
for f in range(2,(len(arr)+1)):
   k=0
   for i in range(2,f//2+1):
      if (f%(int(arr[i]))==0):
        k=k+1
if(k<=0):
    sum=sum+f
print("Sum :",sum)
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. You might want to have your function `return s` and then check the result with `print(sumprimes(n))` instead of `print(sum)`, which is printing something totally unrelated to the problem, the built-in Python function `sum`.

Comment: If this is a question, please [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) one instead of answering and masking your question within the edit summary. Please see [help] and take the [tour].

Answer (score -1):

```
def isPrime(n):
    if (n<2):
        return False
    for i in range (2,n):
        if (n%i==0):
            return False
    return True

li = []
a = [1,10,11,12,13]
for x in a:
    if isPrime(x):
        li.append(x)

print(li)

total = 0
for j in range(len(li)):
    total += li[j]

print(total)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
L = [11,14,13,12,60,50,1]

for a in L:

    if(a % 2 == 0):

     L.remove(a)

for a in L:

    if (a % 3 == 0):

     L.remove(a)

print(sum(L))
```

Comment: This adds nothing over existing answers, does **not** check if the number is prime, and inappropriately mutates a list that you might not “own”.